# How to create a dynamically generated list of selects in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When my user signs up in my angular application, he has to setup his account by adding instruments to his user.

A Instrument looks like this:

```js
export interface Instrument {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    groupId: string;
}
```

The Idea is, that there is a list of dropdowns, which at first only consists of only one dropdown. Beneath the dropdown there is a button, which adds a empty dropdown.
I already achieved this with my code. However when i select a Instrument in the first dropdown and add another instrument via the button, the option in the first dropdown is reset and it looks like nothing is selected (altough the array didn't change besides the new empty value).

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```html
<div 
    *ngFor="let userInstrument of userInstruments; let id = index"
>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex>
        <mat-label>Instument</mat-label>
        <mat-select placeholder="Guitar" [(ngModel)]="userInstruments[id]" name="item">
            <mat-option value="">
                None
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="instrument.id" *ngFor="let instrument of instruments">
                {{instrument.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<p 
    id="add-instrument"
    (click)="addInstrument()"
>
    Add another instrument?
</p>
```

**Typescript**

```js
  userInstruments: string[] = [];
  instruments: Instrument[] = [];

  constructor(private utilsDataSerivce: UtilsDataService) {
    this.utilsDataSerivce.loadInstruments();

    this.utilsDataSerivce.getInstruments$()
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      ).subscribe(i => {
        if (!!i) {
          this.instruments = i;
        }
      })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addInstrument() {
    if (this.addInstrumentValid()) {
      this.userInstruments.push("");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you are trying to set the selected id as a value of userInstrument? So try to replace [(ngModel)]="userInstruments[id]" with [(ngModel)]="userInstrument" this might be a solution

Comment: I think ngModel is going to be deprecated, you can better use the reactive form better to achieve this?

Comment: What will happen when you click button and call add instrument() ?

Comment: @DeepakJha, **not**, [(ngModel)] are not going to be deprecated

Comment: I read this from angular website ```Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in a future version of Angular.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Deepak Jha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2935953/deepak-jha) said in his comment, ngModel is going to be deprecated so i checked the angular material page and they are used `[(value)]="binding"` for the select instead of `[(ngModel)]=binding". That fixed my problem. Thanks!